# Winpe 4 drivers not loading

Tags: windows-8, winpe

I need to inject custom drivers to wim file offline.
I'm using standard scenario described on MSDN http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825206.aspx: mount, add-components (WMI, .NET4), add-drivers (signed, work correctly on windows 7 & 2012, x86/64), unmount, makewinpemedia.
However, when I booting from iso (on VMWare), drivers not loading.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing  while developing Win PE driver is to follow the architecture(using 32 bit on 64 bit Win PE can cause failures)

Follow the steps:-

1. Take the 'Custom Windows PE' rescue CD option in the rescue CD wizard.
2. If you haven't previously installed the Windows Automated Installation Kit (WAIK), then this will need to be downloaded and installed. This is a big (1.7GB) download, so please be patient. The WAIK download dialog will be shown. Just click 'Continue' and be patient while the integration completes.
3. Once the integration is finished cancel the rescue media wizard.
4. Download and run 'inject.exe' from here:

http://updates.macrium.com/reflect/utilities/inject.exe

This will automatically inject the drivers into the windows image file (WIM) and will take a few minutes.

5. Once completed, take the rescue media build wizard again, select the 'Custom Windows PE' and click through to the final page.
6. Click the 'Rebuild' button to re-integrate the WAIK. This will not need to download and install the WAIK again, so will be much quicker.
7. Once completed, if you now burn the rescue CD the drivers will be integrated and you should have no problems booting with the CD and recognizing your local RAID volumes.

Have you gone through Windows Automated Installation Kit (AIK) you can have a look at the following link it may help you.
http://kb.acronis.com/content/24254

Windows PE always uses the same basic VESA mode video driver regardless of the card in use.
Please check the link below.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc160920.aspx

This particular link for creation of the ISO with  Windows Automated Installation Kit (AIK) can also help you get going.
http://www.bootfromcd.com/compare-solutions/windows-pe-boot-disk-review/ 
i did spent some time with Win PE,there is a image below are you getting the same message while booting with VM?
[image]
There are some additional steps given in the follwing link you can check if it works this way
https://users.emulab.net/trac/emulab/wiki/WindowsByWinpe
another helpful link
http://desktopreality.com/windows-7-deployment-the-easy-way/

Updated the information check if it helps.
Thanks